# A question with a continuous limit to a series of discrete random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am trying to answer the following question-

> Let $X_n\sim Geom(\frac\lambda n)$ and $T_n=\frac{X_n}n$. Show that for $n\rightarrow\infty$ the distribution function of $T_n$ converges to the DF of Z, when $Z\sim Exp(\lambda)$.

I would love if anyone helps me with the last stage of my solution:

$P(X_n=x)=(1-\frac\lambda n)^{x-1}(\frac\lambda n)$ so-

$P(T_n=x)=P(X_n=nx)=(1-\frac\lambda n)^{nx-1}(\frac\lambda n)$.

We want $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(T_n=x) = f_Z(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$.

But what I got is:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(T_n=x) =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-\frac\lambda n)^{nx-1}(\frac\lambda n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[(1+\frac1{(\frac n{-\lambda})})^{\frac n{-\lambda}}]^{\frac{-\lambda(nx-1)}n}(\frac\lambda n)  $$

Now $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[(1+\frac1{(\frac n{-\lambda})})^{\frac n{-\lambda}}]^{\frac{-\lambda(nx-1)}n}=e^{-\lambda x}$ which is good, but $\frac\lambda n\rightarrow 0$ which ruins it all.

What did I miss? Seems like there should be multiplication by n but I can't see where.

---

Edit:

As @vvnitram suggested, I tried looking at the distribution functions rather then the density (for the continuous variable) and probability (discrete).

But again, the same problem - since $T_n$ gets only natural values, $$F_{T_n}(k)=P(T_n\leq k)=\sum_{x=1}^k(1-\frac\lambda n)^{ nx-1}(\frac\lambda n)$$

So for every $k\in \Bbb N$, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}F_{T_n}(k)=0$$.

How do I "reach" the continuous random variable at the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$? I tried doing it through the definition of the variable $T_n$ itself, $T_n=\frac{X_n}n$ where $X_n\sim Geom(\frac\lambda n)$, but didn't get anything sensible.

Answer (score 1):

Your work It's OK, but it doesn't work. See that because the limit is a continuous variable, the probability on a point is 0.

To prove this, you can prove that the cumulative $F_n$ converges to $F_X$ with $X\sim exp(\lambda)$